# Can the environment variables tool in windows 10 be launched directly?

Tags: windows-10

One used to be able to chant this incantation to launch the environment variables window.

`C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

What's the replacement for Windows 10?

The DLL Export is still in this file, but it's just not working.

[image: EditEnvironmentVariables]

I'd be happy if someone could help me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C:\Windows\System32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe, even if you still need to click on the  button.

Besides, you can also use the SET and SETX commands in a command prompt.

Pascal